# Appscript extract text from cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, drive, sourceforge-appscript

I have a url in cell https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bApUMcQXwJ4pGMDRNObUwx5Tw1W_3yFN

This url is always the same length, 66 characters

I would like to extract from this url from position 34 to 66

In the example url, the text to extract would be 1bApUMcQXwJ4pGMDRNObUwx5Tw1W_3yFN

Could anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about `url.slice(33);`

[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)